# determine the temporality of a sentence with POS tagging

Tags: r, text-mining, tidytext

I want to find out whether an action has been carried out if will be carried out from a series of sentences.
For example: 
`"I will prescribe this medication"` versus `"I prescribed this medication"` or `"He had already taken the stuff"` versus `"he may take the stuff later"`

I was trying a `tidytext` approach and decided to simply look for past participle versus future participle verbs. However when I POS tag using the only types of verbs I get are `"Verb intransitive"`, `"Verb (usu participle)"` and `"Verb (transitive)"`. How can I get an idea of past or future verbs or is there another POS tagger I can use?

I am keen to use `tidytext` because I cannot install `rjava` which some of the other text mining packages use.

Comment: You could use the package udpipe as a POS tagger. But this will return the word "may" as an auxiliary, not as a future verb

Comment: Look to the morphological features of the udpipe output. It provides you these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the **morphological features** from the `udpipe` annotation. These are put in the **feats** column of the annotation. And you can put these as extra columns in the dataset by using `cbind_morphological`.
All the features are defined at https://universaldependencies.org/u/feat/index.html
You'll see below that prescribed from the sentence 'I prescribed this medication' is **past tense** as well as the word taken and had from 'he had already taken'.

```
library(udpipe)
x <- data.frame(doc_id = 1:4, 
                text = c("I will prescribe this medication", 
                         "I prescribed this medication", 
                         "He had already taken the stuff", 
                         "he may take the stuff later"), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
anno <- udpipe(x, "english")
anno <- cbind_morphological(anno)

anno[, c("doc_id", "token", "lemma", "feats", "morph_verbform", "morph_tense")]

 doc_id      token      lemma                                                  feats morph_verbform morph_tense
      1          I          I             Case=Nom|Number=Sing|Person=1|PronType=Prs           <NA>        <NA>
      1       will       will                                           VerbForm=Fin            Fin        <NA>
      1  prescribe  prescribe                                           VerbForm=Inf            Inf        <NA>
      1       this       this                               Number=Sing|PronType=Dem           <NA>        <NA>
      1 medication medication                                            Number=Sing           <NA>        <NA>
      2          I          I             Case=Nom|Number=Sing|Person=1|PronType=Prs           <NA>        <NA>
      2 prescribed  prescribe                       Mood=Ind|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Fin            Fin        Past
      2       this       this                               Number=Sing|PronType=Dem           <NA>        <NA>
      2 medication medication                                            Number=Sing           <NA>        <NA>
      3         He         he Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Person=3|PronType=Prs           <NA>        <NA>
      3        had       have                       Mood=Ind|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Fin            Fin        Past
      3    already    already                                                   <NA>           <NA>        <NA>
      3      taken       take                               Tense=Past|VerbForm=Part           Part        Past
      3        the        the                              Definite=Def|PronType=Art           <NA>        <NA>
      3      stuff      stuff                                            Number=Sing           <NA>        <NA>
      4         he         he Case=Nom|Gender=Masc|Number=Sing|Person=3|PronType=Prs           <NA>        <NA>
      4        may        may                                           VerbForm=Fin            Fin        <NA>
      4       take       take                                           VerbForm=Inf            Inf        <NA>
      4        the        the                              Definite=Def|PronType=Art           <NA>        <NA>
      4      stuff      stuff                                            Number=Sing           <NA>        <NA>
      4      later      later                                                   <NA>           <NA>        <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks @jwijffels. What about future tense?

Comment: The future tense doesnt see to be there for the word 'will' @jwijffels

Comment: I don't think the english-ewt treebank which was used to build this model has Tense=Fut in that data. If the training data does not contain Tense=Fut, the model also does not have it.